# R find last datetime value between two events

Tags: r, dplyr

I am adding a sample data below. Also adding a screenshot of a desired output to facilitate understanding. In wording I want to find last event (placed_datetime) between 2 events (deposit in product column) . Bear in mind that the column product can contain more distinct values as in reproducible example. it can happen that a player have two or more  deposits in row and no events in between then
I want to have NA values over there. Such situation is also included in RE and the screenshot.
In the screenshot left side is raw data and on the right side list of deposits from raw data and highlighted in yellow last event in between 2 deposits

thanks for help

[image]

```
data<-structure(list(Src_player_Id = c(10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 
                                   10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 
                                   10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 
                                   10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 
                                   10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 
                                   10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 
                                   10274870, 10274870), placed_datetime = structure(c(1580350702, 
                                                                                      1580358268.23252, 1580358485.28439, 1580361468, 1580362947.22817, 
                                                                                      1580365006.9802, 1580368726.16779, 1580369953.98473, 1580411950.92812, 
                                                                                      1580412379.18781, 1580418850.81781, 1580432581.57936, 1580432955.15843, 
                                                                                      1580465229, 1580504609.41338, 1580504901.15106, 1580505161.11841, 
                                                                                      1580550828, 1580562945.16703, 1580563140.89132, 1580563351.21689, 
                                                                                      1580563477, 1580563484.11476, 1580571123.17468, 1580837811, 1580845296.86797, 
                                                                                      1580845843.91141, 1580846042.87572, 1580846145.12245, 1580927530, 
                                                                                      1580935028.38694, 1580935120.13632, 1581508975, 1581515393, 1581517395.39957, 
                                                                                      1581522889.1296, 1581523347.03016, 1581523609.88115, 1581538550, 
                                                                                      1581545860.32047), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                 product = c("deposit", "SB", "SB", "deposit", "SB", "SB", 
                             "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "deposit", "SB", 
                             "SB", "SB", "deposit", "SB", "SB", "SB", "deposit", "SB", 
                             "SB", "deposit", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "deposit", "SB", 
                             "SB", "deposit", "deposit", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "deposit", 
                             "SB")), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
                                                                        "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one more solution

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Src_player_Id) %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(product == "deposit")) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  filter(placed_datetime %in% range(placed_datetime)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(c(grp, Src_player_Id), names_from = product, values_from = placed_datetime) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
   Src_player_Id deposit             SB                 
           <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1      10274870 2020-01-30 02:18:22 2020-01-30 04:28:05
 2      10274870 2020-01-30 05:17:48 2020-01-31 01:09:15
 3      10274870 2020-01-31 10:07:09 2020-01-31 21:12:41
 4      10274870 2020-02-01 09:53:48 2020-02-01 13:22:31
 5      10274870 2020-02-01 13:24:37 2020-02-01 15:32:03
 6      10274870 2020-02-04 17:36:51 2020-02-04 19:55:45
 7      10274870 2020-02-05 18:32:10 2020-02-05 20:38:40
 8      10274870 2020-02-12 12:02:55 NA                 
 9      10274870 2020-02-12 13:49:53 2020-02-12 16:06:49
10      10274870 2020-02-12 20:15:50 2020-02-12 22:17:40
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new group when `product = 'deposit'` and take `first` and `last` `placed_datetime` value in each  `Src_player_Id`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Src_player_Id, grp = cumsum(product == 'deposit')) %>%
  summarise(deposit_time = first(placed_datetime), 
            bet_time = last(placed_datetime), 
            bet_time = replace(bet_time, bet_time == deposit_time, NA)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   dplyr::select(-grp)

#   Src_player_Id deposit_time        bet_time           
#           <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
# 1      10274870 2020-01-30 02:18:22 2020-01-30 04:28:05
# 2      10274870 2020-01-30 05:17:48 2020-01-31 01:09:15
# 3      10274870 2020-01-31 10:07:09 2020-01-31 21:12:41
# 4      10274870 2020-02-01 09:53:48 2020-02-01 13:22:31
# 5      10274870 2020-02-01 13:24:37 2020-02-01 15:32:03
# 6      10274870 2020-02-04 17:36:51 2020-02-04 19:55:45
# 7      10274870 2020-02-05 18:32:10 2020-02-05 20:38:40
# 8      10274870 2020-02-12 12:02:55 NA
# 9      10274870 2020-02-12 13:49:53 2020-02-12 16:06:49
#10      10274870 2020-02-12 20:15:50 2020-02-12 22:17:40
```